# Style Identity server header section

Tags: css, identityserver4

I am trying to find out where/if I can style the header section in Identity Server 4. This is how my page looks. I have modified the body section but am not sure where the header section lies.

[image]

Comment: I have never used identity server but nearly any HTML can be styled by using inspector available in browsers and overriding the CSS (Using `! important` tags). NOTE: THIS SHOULD ONLY BE USED AS YOUR LAST RESORT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open **_Layout.cshtml** in **Views/Shared** folder.

[image: Sample of _Layout.cshtml]

Answer (score 1):

There is a layout page in a shared folder that sets the page structure. Found it there.